# Making tooltips in dynamically generated lists

Tags: list, dynamic, tooltip, smarty

At www.euroworker.no/order I have been trying to add a tooltip function but it seems I have misunderstood it. Is there a simple tooltip I can use in this list? IT needs to display image and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest tooltip ever.

```
a:hover {background:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;} /*BG color is a must for IE6*/
a.tooltip span {display:none; padding:2px 3px; margin-left:8px; width:130px;}
a.tooltip:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #cccccc; color:#6c6c6c;}
```

With this simple HTML:

```
Easy <a class="tooltip" href="#">Tooltip<span>This is the crazy little Easy Tooltip Text.</span></a>.
```

Comment: Why display>inline? Why not block?

Comment: I guess both would work, just happened to be the one I was using :)